# GCloud terminal : unable to exit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am using gcloud terminal on windows.
just ran gcloud help, it shown all the available commands and finally a prompt which shows `(END)`.
But from there I am unable to exit that prompt and move on.
I tried Ctrl+C, Ctrl+Z . but no use

[image]

what kind of editor is that? is it specific to gcloud console? or a common one? is there a --help/man which shows these commands? How would someone know to press a specific input to exit , and probably other commands as-well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the **less** pager, a common Linux default. Type **h** to see the available commands. You can scroll and search forward/back.

On Windows you will get a gcloud-specific pager that has a common subset of **less** commands, also listed by the **h** command. We opted for that over the Windows **more** pager because it lacks backward scroll/search.

If you have a favorite pager then on Windows:

```
set PAGER=*your-favorite-pager-command-name*
```

and on Linux:

```
export PAGER=*your-favorite-pager-command-name*
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to press the letter q to "quit" from that.

Comment: Thanks..  what kind of editor is that? is it specific to gcloud console? or a common one? is there a --help/man which shows these commands? How would someone know to press "q" to exit , and probably other commands as-well

Comment: You can press "h" for help.

Answer (score 0):

following the relevant gcloud documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console

in order to disconnect from the serial console you need to run
"~."
that is a tilda "~" followed by a dot "."